Gstreamer pipeline - How to reference a src elemement
I want to use the fallbacksrc in a gst-launch-1.0 pipeline.
The fallbacksrc require a source param that referencce a base source element.
How can I specify this source element in a pipeline?
I have tried this way using name= to create a reference, but did not work
gst-launch-1.0  \
     rtspsrc location=rtsp://cam.local:8554/stream name=src1 \
     ! fallbacksrc fallback-uri=file:no_video.jpg source=src1 \
     ! decodebin ! videoscale \
     ! videoconvert \
     ! autovideosink

